# How to create a unique hash on a row in sqlite when inserting into a table

Tags: sqlite, hash

I want to create a unique hash for each row that is inserted to a table

I want to index the hash -

Currently I have this in place

```
CREATE TABLE 'products' (
    'sku'   TEXT PRIMARY KEY, 
    'group_id'  TEXT,
    'name'  TEXT,
    'full_name TEXT',
... 20+ columns 
);

CREATE TABLE 'hash' (
    'key' TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    'hash' TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TRIGGER hash_gen 
    AFTER INSERT 
    ON 'products'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO hash(
        key,
        hash
    )
    VALUES(
        new.sku,
        new.sku | new.group_id | new.name | new.full_name | ...
-- I want to create a hash on all of the values that were inserted - 
I've tried one pipe "|" (BITWISE OR?) and 
    two pipes "||" (concat) but would ideally like something along FAST_HASH(new.all_values)
    );
END;


CREATE INDEX hash_gen_index
ON hash_gen (hash);
```

My DB has 2M rows and is being populated from external CSV files often so it should be quick as possible

When using the concat operator `"||"` the population of the database was extremely slow (over 10 minutes vs 2 previously) so it isn't a viable option as it also bloated the db by more than x3.

When using just the "OR" operator `"|"` I got many duplicates of the hash as can be seen from this query (Also I suspect it won't behave the same across different architectures i.e. MacOS vs. Linux)

When using the single pipe `"|"` operator I get bad diversity of the hash

```
select count(*) from hash where hash=6283263
> 7831
```

Comment: How you convert the concat(ALL TEXT's) to a number? iam not seeing that?

Comment: it does it on its own when using single pipe "|"

Comment: Why can't you use your own hash function?

Comment: How do i create a hash function in the sqlite cli without compiling a c library